# Composer telling me mbstring is missing on my server, but it is installed enabled - ideas?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, mbstring

I have laravel 5.3 site running on digitalocean with Ubunto 14.

I get this error when running composer to install a package:

**"the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system."**

The thing is, it is already enabled, as confirmed by phpinfo:

```
mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
oniguruma version   5.9.6
```

Since I have php7.0 running, for kicks I tried

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

But it tells me

```
php7.0-mbstring is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Really at a loss here. Ideas? Maybe I need to reinstall PHP? Where is composer looking to see if the extension is installed? Why would it n0t be seeing same info that phpinfo returns?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring ` command on your server

Comment: Maybe it is installed but not enabled, you can check your `php.ini` for this.

Comment: Check that it's enabled in both the cli and the web server php.ini files

Comment: what output do you get when you run `php -v` on terminal? and what it shows on phpinfo? maybe you have different php versions going on.

Comment: Please check your php config file. Maybe you have to add a line "extension=php7.0-mbstring.so" in php.ini. Please have a look: https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu

Comment: That worked, thanks! Any idea what the underlying issue could have been?

Comment: Is that command worked??

Comment: php -v returns 7.1.8, but phpinfo returns 7.0.22.

Comment: Hiren, yes it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to install `php-mbstring` in your server.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

You need  to install the specific `php` version using :

```
sudo apt-get install phpx.x-mbstring
```

Hope this works!!